# Editing the question: "How to become solution-oriented and self-organized?"

Tags: discussion, editing

I've decided to some editing during my tea breaks and I found this question:

[How to become solution-oriented and self-organized?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/3005/468)

My first action was to delete the parts starting with the "Answers" section, because it clearly belongs to somewhere else. On the other hand if I had deleted it how would have we known which answer was the most useful for the OP?

What do you think? What's your guideline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate your efforts to edit this, but I'm not sure this question can be saved.

First, I'm not sure this would be on topic since it doesn't seem to be about project management.

Second, the question is really, *really* vague. The asker doesn't give enough detail to give a solid answer. The other signal that tells me something is wrong is the fact that Trevor's answer is one big clarifying question to try to get more details out of the asker.

We have been closing old questions in different tags that don't fit the new scope, and this is likely one we might close as "Not a Real Question", since it's so vague.

With that said, editing doesn't hurt. If I were to edit, I would remove the answer in the question. We can't really do anything about the asker not accepting an answer, only he can do that.

Also, you should know that I've actually seen questions that I thought were dead get turned around by some editors with vision who saw some glimmer of hope that I missed, so please don't let me discourage you if you *really* think it can be fixed! I just feel that you should know that this one is more than likely on the chopping block, in case you have other questions you'd prefer to give your time and attention to :) Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, it helps. I won't do anything with this one ;-)